# How to use ion-refresher if the page has more than 1 div in ionic 1

Tags: angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework

I want to use ion-refresher for a html page which is having 3 div elements. Each div element will do different functions like allShow(), earnedShow() and redeemShow().

I'm using popover component to filter my data. For example, 'All' will have all data, 'Earned' will display only earned details and 'Redeemed' will display only redeemed details. I've written all the views in a single html itself. What I want is, when I'm in 'Earned' field, and if I'm trying to pull refresh the page means, only the function responsible to that div should appear, it should not go to 'All'

Please suggest a way how to use this

```js
      $scope.allShow = function()
  {
 $scope.All = true;
 $scope.Earned = false;
 $scope.Redeemed = false; 

  //some function
  }
        $scope.earnedShow = function()
  {
 $scope.All = false;
 $scope.Earned = true;
 $scope.Redeemed = false; 
  //some function
  }
        $scope.redeemShow = function()
  {
 $scope.All = false;
 $scope.Earned = false;
 $scope.Redeemed = true; 
  //some function
  }
  
  $scope.doRefresh = function() {

    console.log('Refreshing!');
    $timeout( function() {

  // $scope.allShow();
    

    $scope.allShow();
     $scope.$broadcast('scroll.refreshComplete');
    
    }, 500);
      
  };
```

```html
 <ion-content scroll="true" >

     <ion-refresher on-refresh="doRefresh()" pulling-text="Pull to refresh...">
</ion-refresher>

 <div  ng-show="All" >All
 </div>
  <div  ng-show="Earned" >Earned
 </div>
  <div  ng-show="Redeemed" >Redeemed
 </div>
</ion-content>
```

Comment: it's not clear at all what you are asking here.  with the code you have posted, none of these `div` will ever be visible, because all of the `ng-show` are pointing to `$scope` properties that don't exist.

Comment: $scope.All = false;
  $scope.Earned = false;
     $scope.Redeemed = true;

Comment: These are the scope variables I'm using for every functions to display the respective function. I'm getting the content now. Problem is I need to refresh that particuar scope only

Comment: `$scope` is per controller, not per function;  it's still not really clear what you are trying to do here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should refresh depending the current selected div. There are plenty simple solution, but for your logic:

```
$scope.doRefresh = function() {
  console.log('Refreshing!');
  $timeout( function() {    
    if ($scope.All === true) {
      $scope.allShow();
    }
    if ($scope.Earned === true) {
      $scope.earnedShow();
    }
    if ($scope.Redeemed === true) {
      $scope. redeemShow();
    }
    $scope.$broadcast('scroll.refreshComplete');
}, 500);
```

could be the solution